# how to update sqlite table with specific row and not repeat the exist row ?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have some table that contain a students. 
The table is build of those column:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + STUDENTS_TABLE
                                + "(" + STUDENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
                                + STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                + GROUP + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
```

I need to update the table in case the user want to add new student. 
So, in case the user add new student - i add the student to code map and then i update the database with all the exist students that i hold in the map.

In this case i have duplicate student .. with different id but with same name and group.

I don't want to delete the table and then add each of the student.

I looking for some other way.

Can someone help me here ?

I want to update only the student that are not int the database.

Comment: Does adding a UNIQUE constraint on the table with the constraint on 'name' and 'group' not work for your requirements?

Comment: if i knew hownto do it .. so maybe :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Unique constraint to your Create Table Statement:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + STUDENTS_TABLE
                                + "(" + STUDENT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "
                                + STUDENT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                + GROUP + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                                + CONSTRAINT name_unique UNIQUE (STUDENT_NAME, GROUP));";
```

Now you will not be able to insert a entry with the same STUDENT_NAME and GROUP. Of course you may have to handle an error.

Alternatively you could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO STUDENTS_TABLE(Field1,Field2, ...) 
SELECT value1, value2, ...
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT STUDENT_NAME FROM STUDENTS_TABLE WHERE STUDENT_NAME = valueName AND GROUP = valueGroup);
```

The "..." are in case you need to add more values into more fields.